# Images Not Showing in a table when PHP echo but will show if just in html

Tags: php, html, css, image

I am using the following code on a PHP page. When I load the page, the data shows up but the  tag will not show anything other than a dot. If I add style="height:11px; width:16px", it shows a very very thin line (same goes if I just add height="11px" width="16px"

I can view the rendered html code and the img src is correct, it will display no problems. I can add, outside of my PHP script, an [image]
 as an example, and it displays just fine. So I am missing something within this snippet of code which is causing my grief?

I've looked in the Inspector tool in Chrome and I don't have any obvious errors other than a javascript error but I don't think that should be causing the issue.

The test page witho nly the two css. It works when I only have bootstrap.css but goes away when I add on the style.css

http://cronkflies.com/test5.php

```
<!-- Top Routes -->
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="background:white;">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" colspan="2"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $lang_top_routes ?></span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                  <tbody>


                    <tr>
                      <td>
                         <?php
                            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                            $path .= "/includes/connections/mysqli.php";
                            require($path);

                            $sql = "SELECT vertrekluchthaven, lh.luchthavencode AS vertrek, lh.luchthavennaam AS vnaam, lh.countryflag AS vflag, aankomstluchthaven, lh2.luchthavennaam AS anaam, lh2.luchthavencode AS aankomst, lh2.countryflag AS aflag, COUNT(*) AS count

                                    FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

                                    INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
                                    ON vg.vertrekluchthaven = lh.luchthavenID

                                    INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh2
                                    ON vg.aankomstluchthaven = lh2.luchthavenID

                                    WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=Now()

                                    GROUP BY vertrekluchthaven, aankomstluchthaven
                                    ORDER BY count DESC
                                    LIMIT 10;";

                            $result = $result = $link->query($sql);

                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                                echo"  <table class='table'>";
                                echo "  <tbody>";

                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                $vflag = $row['vflag'];
                                $aflag = $row['aflag'];

                                echo "    <tr>";
                                echo "      <td align='center'><img src='http://cronkflies.com/img/flags/" . $vflag . "'></td>";
                                echo "      <td ><div class='top10_luchthaven' data-tooltip=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['vnaam'])."\" >".$row['vertrek']."</div></td>";
                                echo "      <td ><strong class='home_statistieks_label'>&nbsp;-</strong></td>";
                                echo "      <td ><img src='http://cronkflies.com/img/flags/".$aflag."'></td>";
                                echo "      <td ><div class='top10_luchthaven' data-tooltip=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['anaam'])."\" >".$row['aankomst']."</div></td>";
                                echo "      <td ><strong class='home_statistieks_label'><div align='center'>".$row['count']."</div></strong></td>";
                                echo "    </tr>";

                            }
                                echo "  </tbody>";
                                echo "</table>";

                                    }

                            $link->close();

                            ?>  

                      </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle, it'll greatly help to see it live. Just to mention, you should close your `img` tags - `<img />`

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky in HTML5 you do not need to close tags.

Comment: What's about the developer tools of your browser ? The image is loaded ? Or you have a 404 error ?

Comment: So to be clear, when you load your page, let's call it 'index.php', the image doesn't load correctly.  But if you view-source, select all, copy, open a file let's call 'index.html', paste the rendered HTML there, save the file, and then load 'index.html', the image displays properly?

Comment: Compare the actual output from the PHP code, rather than the PHP itself.  That is, view the page, and then View Source in your browser.  How is it different than the raw HTML that you know works?

Comment: I'm working diligently on this. It would seem that there is maybe something in one of the css files that is causing this issue... I just now need to break it down. It would seem that they load just fine when the bootstrap.css file is included in the header and no other files, but when I add the style CSS it goes away again. I've posted links to the test page because I'm not sure how to do it with a fiddle.

Comment: I have resolved this. It seems to be related to the size of the col and the size of the td's. I changed the class to a tablesorter class and then the images showed right up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should have the same amount of columns in the header `<th></th>` as in the row `<td></td>`